# bash using two arguments inside case, increasing variable after every cycle in POSIX

Tags: bash

I have code below. I want to increase iter after every for cycle by 1. If cycle finds "-a", I'd like to case do: set swticha to true and set posa to actual value of iter. Is it possible anyway? Thank you!

```
iter=0
for var in "$@"
do
  filtry $var "$((iter))"
  $iter=$(iter+1)
done

filtry()
{
    case $1 in
      -a)
        switcha=true
        posa=$2;;
      -b) switchb=true;;
      -ip) switchip=true;;
      -uri) switchuri=true;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: I mean, I'd like to get if first argument is -a posa on value 1, but if it's thrird argument, posa should be set on 3.

Comment: In `$iter=$(iter+1)`, you can't use `$` on the left side of an assignment (`$` *gets* the value of a variable, so don't use it when *setting* the value). Also, `$( )` executes its contents as a command; to do math, use `$(( ))` instead. Finally, you must define `filtry` *before* you use it.

Comment: BTW, it looks like you're trying to reinvent `getopts` -- I'd look at using that instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to reinvent getopts, but I need to use more than one chr identificators.